# can't drag events in FullCalendar if I hide some dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar and I'm trying to hide the weeks that come before my starting date. 
it works perfectly and but the problem that I can't drag my events anymore. 
I don't find another way to do that, and what is the problem in my code. 
this is my attempt

```js
$(window).load(function () {
  
  var startDate = $('#start_date').val();

  //hide all dates before starting date
  $('#save').click(function(){
          
   $(".fc-day").each(function() { 
    var startTraining = $('#start_date').val();
    var tdDate = new Date ($(this).data('date'));
    var startDate = new Date (startTraining);
              
    if ((tdDate < startDate) && (($(this).parent().get(0)) !== ($('.fc-day[data-date="' + startTraining + '"]').parent().get(0)))){
     $(this).closest('.fc-row').addClass('hidden');
    } else {
     $(this).closest('.fc-row').removeClass('hidden');
    }
     
   });
          
  });


  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', startDate);
  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();
  var started;
  var categoryClass;
  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    right: 'title'
   },
   selectable: true,
   selectHelper: true,
   select: function (start, end, allDay) {
    $('#fc_create').click();
    started = start;
    ended = end
    
    $(".antosubmit").on("click", function () {
     var title = $("#title").val();
     if (end) {
      ended = end
     }
     
     categoryClass = $("#event_type").val();
     
     if (title) {
      calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
       title: title,
       start: started,
       end: end,
       allDay: allDay
      },
      true // make the event "stick"
      );
     }
     
     $('#title').val('');
     calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
     $('.antoclose').click();
     return false;
    });
   },
   
   eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
   
   //alert(calEvent.title, jsEvent, view);
    $('#fc_edit').click();
    $('#title2').val(calEvent.title);
    categoryClass = $("#event_type").val();
    $(".antosubmit2").on("click", function () {
     calEvent.title = $("#title2").val();
     calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', calEvent);
     $('.antoclose2').click();
    });
    
    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
   },
   
   editable: true,
   events: [
    {
     title: 'All Day Event',
     start: new Date(y, m, 1)
    }, {
     title: 'All Day Event',
     start: new Date(y, m, 8)
    }, {
     title: 'All Day Event',
     start: new Date(y, m, 15)
    }, {
     title: 'All Day Event',
     start: new Date(y, m, 22)
    }, {
     title: 'All Day Event',
     start: new Date(y, m, 29)
    }
   ]
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.7.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.7.1/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <input type="text" value="" id="start_date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">
   <button type="button" id="save">Save</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="container">
    <div id='calendar'></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution if anyone need this.

```
    $('#save').click(function(){

        $(".fc-day").each(function() {  
            var startTraining = $('#start_date').val();
            var tdDate = new Date ($(this).data('date'));
            var startDate = new Date (startTraining);

            if ((tdDate < startDate) && (($(this).parent().get(0)) !== ($('.fc-day[data-date="' + startTraining + '"]').parent().get(0)))){
                $(this).closest('.fc-row').addClass('invisible');
            } else {
                $(this).closest('.fc-row').removeClass('invisible');
            }

        });

    });

.invisible {
    visibility: hidden; 
    height:0px !important; 
    min-height:0px !important; 
    line-height:0px !important
}
```